# How do I measure the amount of time a mouse click was held for using pynput?

Tags: python, mouseevent, pynput

I'm creating an application where I want to measure how long a mouse click was held for. I've given it a couple attempts and want to see where I'm going wrong.

```
def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    if pressed:
        pressTime = time()
        print(pressTime)

    if not pressed:
        releaseTime = time()
        print(releaseTime)

    print(pressTime - releaseTime)

with mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

I expect an output of the difference between the two times, but I get an error telling me that I've tried to use a variable without initializing it (either pressTime or releaseTime).

Answer (score 0):

You need used `global` variable

```
# declare two variable
pressTime, releaseTime

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global pressTime, releaseTime

    ...
```